# Embed youtube video inside TextKit

Tags: ios, ios8, textkit

I am trying to display a html page from a website on iPad. Instead of using UIWebview, I used Textkit so I can display the content in multiple columns. I used iOS7 Day-by-Day day 21 example as reference.

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/18/ios7-day-by-day-day-21-multi-column-textkit-text-rendering

It worked fine except the video does not show up at all. The video embeded in the HTML page is youtube videos.

Could anyone let me know if it is possible to show youtube video in textKit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to handle it automatically, but you can put an NSTextAttachment in there with a placeholder image. Then when the user taps in the attachment you can bring up a new view controller with the video.